# Can cURL library be used for HTTPS communication on iOS to be compatible with ATS(Application Transport Security) requirement?

Tags: ios9, libcurl, ios10, app-transport-security

Apple mandates ATS(Application Transport Security) support for application from Jan 2017. From Apple tech note on ATS : "ATS is enforced by the NSURLSession class and all APIs that use it."

I am using cURL library for HTTP communication in my application. Now I need to use same for HTTPS to confirm to ATS limitation. But there is no clear information if Apple will allow HTTPS requests from 3rd party libraries like cURL.

And for cURL, is it compatible with ATS specification. cURL does provide a compile time switch "--darwin-ssl" to use platform SSL library. But does it make cURL compliant with ATS requirements.